# find if there is any string in a line after matching regex bash

Tags: bash, awk, grep

In a file looking like below I would to find if all lines with "PRIO" has any value after that and if there are some values missing I would like to write it as output.

I've tried to do this with grep, but it only matches if there's even one occurrence of looking word.

```
cat PATH_TO_FILE | grep 'PRIO' &> /dev/null

if [ $? == 0 ]; then
    echo "matched"
else
    echo "not found"
fi
```

File structure looks simillar to this one below

```
name1
sdgk
PRIO     3


name2
PRIO
dsl        dfhhhdf

name3
fnslkf hsdhfd    
jlkg;jslk sgdgdsg 
kfasdjmgkdlsgl      sdggsehg
PRIO 1 


name4
sdgds
dsdsgdg
PRIO              2
sdgg
```

Comment: Please provide us with code samples of what you tried until now. That way we can help you more effectively.

Comment: In addition to the [useless use of `cat`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html) you also want to avoid explicitly examining `$?`.  The very *purpose*  of `if` is to run a command and examine its exit code.  So; `if grep -q '^PRIO.*[0-1]'` PATH_TO_FILE; then ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With awk this is very simple by checking the number of fields.

`awk '/PRIO/{ str=(NF>1)?"matched":"not found"; print str }' <file>`

This does :

- `/PRIO/` : if a line contains the word `PRIO` perform action `{...}`
- `{...}` : if the number for fields is bigger then 1 `(NF>1)1, it matched otherwise it did not.

If you want to ensure that `PRIO` is the first word, then use `$1=="PRIO"`, and if you want to print the line number then use

`awk '($1=="PRIO"){ str=(NF>1)?"matched":"not found"; print NR,str }' <file>`

Comment: Thank you for help. And if I want to look if there are only numbers in the line after matching "PRIO"(values should be in a range between 1-5)?

Comment: You can use the regex `/^[[:blank:]]*PRIO[[:blank:]]*[1-5][[:blank]]*$/`, this will check if the line contains 2  columns where the first ons is PRIO and the second a nummer. This could also be written as `(NF==2)&&($1=="PRIO")&&($2~/[1-5]/)`.

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you want to test but

```
$ grep -q 'PRIO\s*$' file
```

checks whether there are any PRIO without any value after.  For your sample input this will succeed, which you can use this as an error condition.

```
if grep -q 'PRIO\s*$' file
then echo "found missing value instance"
else echo "all instances have values"
fi
```

Comment: `\s` is not supported by most `grep` implementations.